# Creating Modals in VS code

Tags: javascript, loops

I can't get my modals to work. The first one works, but the rest do not. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried different variations of a for loop and forEach method but nothing works.

```
    <div class="modal hidden" id='modal1'>
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <img
        src="./Images/alstroemeria.jpg"
        alt="Three pink and
            white flowers with a yellow and white center with green stems.
            Lavender flower is faded in the background."
      />
      <h2>Alstroemeria</h2>
      <p>
        It's symbolic of wealth, prosperity and fortune. It is also the flower
        of friendship.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
    
      <button class="btn">Siberian Iris</button>
      <div class="modal hidden" id='modal2'>
      <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
      <img
      src="./Images/siberian-iris.jpeg"
      width="200"
      height="200"
      alt="A close up photo of a flower with various hues of blue, purple, and yellow. The flower has vein like designs on most of the petals."
    />
    <h2>Siberian Iris</h2>
    <p>
      <h2>Siberian Iris</h2>
      It symbolizes eloquence. Purple iris is symbolic of wisdom and
      compliments. Blue iris symbolizes faith and hope. Yellow iris symbolizes
      passion while white iris symbolizes purity.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
```

This JS code only works for the first button but not the second button:

```
const modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
const openModal = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".close-modal");
const overlay = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay");

const showModal = () => {
 modal.classList.remove("hidden");
 overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
};

const closeModal = () => {
 modal.classList.add("hidden");
 overlay.classList.add("hidden");
};

openModal.addEventListener("click", showModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
```

I tried these loops separately, but they don't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (let i = 1; i < modal.length; i++) {
  openModal[i].addEventListener("click", showModal);
  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
  overlay.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
}

modal.forEach(function (modals) {
  modals.addEventListener("click", function () {
    showModal();
  });
});
```

Comment: use `this` inside of your click callback to reference the current dom object and not the single modal one stored in the variable.

Comment: Where do I use that? In one of the loops? I'm pretty new to JS.   I should also add that the first modal only works if I used querySelector instead of querySelectorAll in the variables.